# using react-native-google-signin with Firebase auth (android implementation)

Tags: firebase-authentication, react-native

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/blob/HEAD/docs/android-guide.md) for implementing this module to the letter.....however Im still getting error:

```
Could not resolve project :react-native-google-signin.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-google-signin:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

UPDATE 5/5/20
Below is the line of code that is causing the issue.....its in file `settings.gradle`

```
project(':react-native-google-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin/android')
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Which RN -v you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out what I was doing wrong.

As Im using RN >= 0.60.....autolinking is used so I didnt need to add code to settings.gradle